# grails select is not rendering value

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I want to make a select box in grails. I am using 2.1.0. I have a view page which shows a select box named class. But it does not shows any value. The list I have used in the from attribute of select works fine is browser when I render it as json. Can anyone make my combo box work for me please ? Here is my code below :

my view page >>>

```
<g:form controller="admistratorAction" action="addStudent">
    <table class="centerTable">
        <div class="height"></div>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Full Name :</label></td>
            <td><g:textField name="fullname" id="fullname" class="field"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label>Admission Class :</label></td>
            <td><g:select name="class" id="class"  class="field" from="${classList}" noSelection="['':'-Choose a class-']"/></td>
        </tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><g:submitButton name="createSubmit" value="Create" class="button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure???')"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</g:form>
```

here is my controller >>

```
 package administrator

import common.classes.Classes
import grails.converters.JSON

class AdmistratorActionController {

def addStudent = {
    render "add student"
}


    def classList = {
        def classes = Classes.executeQuery("SELECT  c.classes FROM Classes c")
        def all_class = [classes : classes]
        render all_class as JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: but how your `classList` is related to the view? how it supposed to work together?

Comment: I don't know. Should I import my controller in view page. If to do so then how ?

Comment: I think it's better to read Grails docs, to understand how it works. Like http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#understandingControllersAndActions

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert it to JSON in order to have it in gsp page

```
class AdmistratorActionController {

    def addStudent = {
        def n = params.fullName
        def c = params.class
        // do something with them
    }

    def classList = {
        def classes = Classes.list()
        // pass details to view 'classList'
        [classList : classes]
    }
}
```

Create -> views/administratorAction/classList.gsp
have you form ready and you will be able to get ${classList} in it